# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have this query and its work fine for me

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ','+SLT_SubListName  FROM sublists where SLT_SubListId in (1,2)  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

but when i change the in parameters **(1,2)** into the **'select SBS_SubListId from subscriber where SBS_SubscriberId=1'**
which also return the **1,2**

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ','+SLT_SubListName  FROM sublists where SLT_SubListId in (select SBS_SubListId from subscriber where SBS_SubscriberId=1
)  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

its giving me the error which is the following

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,4,5' to data type int.

if anybody needs i can also post my table schema here.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to first split these comma sepered values on comma bases, and then apply converrsion.

Comment: because when applying conversion, the compiler will change an element say '75' to integer 75, so when it finds ',' in the element list, it can't convert it into integer...thats why...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect tht your subquery is returning one entry of "1,2,4,5" which is not an integer. You need to get it to return 4 rows with one of these in each.

If you are doing this - show the results of the subquery - then you may have type differences.

Answer (score 0):

Since your subquery seems to be returning the varchar '1,2,4,5', you can try the query using CONTAINS:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ','+SLT_SubListName  FROM sublists where CONTAINS((select SBS_SubListId from subscriber where SBS_SubscriberId=1), SLT_SubListId 
)  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

That way it treats the results from the subquery as text.